# Kotlin sealed class when expression not working in compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have following code:

```
sealed class ChooseCarState {
 data class ShowCarsState(val car: Int) : ChooseCarState()
 object ShowLoadingState : ChooseCarState()
 data class ShowError(val message: String) : ChooseCarState()
}
```

when observe this sealed class from ViewModel in composable function:

```
@Composable
fun showCars(){
val state = viewModel.chooseCarState.collectAsState()
when(state.value){
    is ChooseCarState.ShowCarsState->{
        val car = (state.value as ChooseCarState.ShowCarsState).car
    }
    is ChooseCarState.ShowLoadingState->{

    }
    is ChooseCarState.ShowError ->{
        val message  = (state.value as ChooseCarState.ShowError).message
    }
  }
}
```

I got ClassCastException, in spite of the fact that I am casting in `is` statement.

What could be a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that from the compiler's point of view, there is no guarantee that `state.value` will always return the same value, since it is not a final field.
You can solve this by assigning `state.value` to a variable which <s>you can then safely cast.</s> is then available for smart casts.

```
@Composable
fun showCars(){
val state = viewModel.chooseCarState.collectAsState()
when(val currentState = state.value){
    is ChooseCarState.ShowCarsState->{
        val car = currentState.car
    }
    is ChooseCarState.ShowLoadingState->{

    }
    is ChooseCarState.ShowError ->{
        val message  = currentState.message
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just for completeness sake: the same applies if you use the `val state by viewModel.chooseCarState.collectAsState()` syntax

Comment: Would that be fine to call below?

when(val state = viewModel.chooseCarState.collectAsState().value){
// consume state
}